# PDE files as GLSL shaders?

Tags: glsl, shader

Is it possible to convert a PDE file into GLSL form
There is nothing I can find on the subject online. I dont know if this is even semi possible, but a solution or a confirmation of its impossibilty would be appreciated.

I have searched for hours and there is not much infomation if any at all online on the topic.